# invalid number exception(ORA-01722) while executing IN clause in preparedstatement

Tags: java, oracle11g

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(123458686L);
list.add(585858424L);
list.add(688584241L);

String empcomm = list.stream.map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

PreparedStatement pstmt= con.prepareStatement("select * from emp where empid=? and empidList in(?))");

  pstmt.setLong(1,123458686L);
  pstmt.setString(2,empcomm);
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

I am getting invalid number exception(ORA-01722) while executing above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that's not going to work, you're looking for `setArray()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html